# Error en phpmyadmin `Error: 1231`

Tags: phpmyadmin

Al iniciar phpmyadmin me aparece el siguiente error:

### [image: error phpmyadmin]

Al actualizar la página se soluciona y puedo entrar a la interfaz, pero quisiera sacar ese error que es molesto cada vez que entro.

Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Error: 1231 SQLSTATE: 42000 (ER_WRONG_VALUE_FOR_VAR)
>
> Message: Variable '%s' can't be set to the value of '%s'

[mysql-error-messages](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_wrong_value_for_var)

Revisa el config.inc.php

```
$cfg['Lang'] = 'es_ES';
```

Si esta bien, revisa el my.cnf de tu servidor MySQL por si tuviera algun valor del tipo

```
lc-messages=es_ES
```

Comment: el archivo que tuve que modificar era "config.default.php". el parámetro estaba vacío: $cfg['Lang'] = '';

Comment: Bien por indicarlo. LA verdad es que hace tiempo que no instalo un phpmyadmin, y ya no recordaba si era config.inc.php o config.default.inc.php. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer es un problema que esta documentado:

https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11778

actualiza a la última versión estable de PhpmyAdmin!

Comment: Gracias, pero tengo la última versión.